# How to get local mouse position

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get local position of cursor?

I want (0,0) point to be in top left corner of my window, not the whole screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Cursor.Position` class.

If you want to map global mouse position to your window relative position, then use:

```
YourFormControl.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
```